# Add product labels like "New" , "Sale" in shopify theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to make a demo for a client who wants product label like

> new
> hotselling
> featured

Please suggest how do I achieve it without using any apps

Comment: you need to utilize the product tags to add the same to the frontend.

Comment: You can use the `created_at`/`published_at` for the `new` badge and `compared_price` for the `sale`, but we need to see what have you tried on your own to help you here.

Comment: found the answer at the theme document, https://archetypethemes.co/blogs/support/can-i-add-custom-new-or-coming-soon-labels-to-my-products?_pos=1&_sid=c2b28cb8c&_ss=r